# ngTable filter customization to a single inputText above the table

Tags: angularjs, filter, ngtable

How do I use ngTable with a custom filter inputText, that is common to all the columns ? I know ngTable filter can be turned off to not show the inputText boxes above the column, but I want to have a single inputText placed above the table or outside the table, when any value entered, it will be filtered across all the columns.

Appreciate any help.

TIA.

Here is my code, I use a hidden column that consist of all the values across the row. This is not perfect.

```js
    $scope.ngTableData =[
  {"colAB": "testA1testB1", "colA": "testA1", "colB": "testB1"},
  {"colAB": "testA2testB2", "colA": "testA2", "colB": "testB2"},
  {"colAB": "testA3testB3", "colA": "testA3", "colB": "testB3"},
  {"colAB": "testA4testB4", "colA": "testA4", "colB": "testB4"},
  {"colAB": "testA5testB5", "colA": "testA5", "colB": "testB5"},
  {"colAB": "testA12testB12", "colA": "testA12", "colB": "testB12"},
  {"colAB": "testA13testB13", "colA": "testA13", "colB": "testB13"},
  {"colAB": "testA14testB14", "colA": "testA14", "colB": "testB14"}
 
 ] ;
    
    $scope.filter= {
         
        colAB: undefined
    };
    
    var dataArr = $scope.ngTableData.length;
    
    $scope.userTable = new NgTableParams({
        
                page: 1,
                count: 5,
                filter: $scope.filter
        
            }, {
                
                total: $scope.ngTableData.length,
                getData: function ($defer, params) {
                    
     var orderedData = params.sorting() ?
         $filter('orderBy')($scope.ngTableData,                                                                  params.orderBy()) : $scope.ngTableData;
     orderedData = 
        $filter('filter')(orderedData,                                                                        params.filter());
     params.total(orderedData.length);
     defer.resolve(             
      orderedData.slice((params.page() - 1) *                                                             params.count(), params.page() *  params.count()) 
     );
  
                }
    });
```

```html
    <label>Search: </label>
    <input ng-model="filter.colAB">
    <table ng-table="userTable" show-filter="false" class="table table-striped">      
        <tr ng-repeat="user in $data ">
      
            <td data-title="'Col A'" sortable="'colA'" filter='{ "colA": "text" }'>
            
                {{user.colA}}
            </td>
            
            <td data-title="'Col B'" sortable="'colB'" filter="{ 'colB': 'text' }">
            
                {{user.colB}}
            </td>
            
             <td filter='{ "colAB": "text" }' ng-if="false">
                {{user.colAB}}
            
            </td>
        
        </tr>
      
    </table>
```

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far to solve your problem, it will be helpful for us to answer your question. SO is Q&A site for coding problem, not help forum.

Comment: Here is the code I use, its not perfect also I am using hidden column with all the concat values.

Answer (score 1):

You can supply an object with a property named `$` with the value of your global filter to the method filter() of the instance of NgTableParams. Look at the example snippet below:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ["ngTable"]);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, NgTableParams) {
  var data = [
    {name:'Ana', age:12, money:38945, country:'pan'},
    {name:'Ric', age:34, money:34945, country:'cr'},
    {name:'Rob', age:76, money:34845, country:'col'},
    {name:'Stu', age:23, money:34895, country:'ven'},
    {name:'Amy', age:22, money:34894, country:'usa'},
    {name:'Jay', age:77, money:34895, country:'mex'}
  ];

  $scope.tableParams = new NgTableParams({},  {dataset: data});

  // For use with global search button
  $scope.makeGlobalSearch = function() {
    var term = $scope.globalSearchTerm;
    /** L@@K HERE **/
    $scope.tableParams.filter({ $: term });
  };

  // Watcher for global search without button
  $scope.$watch('globalSearchTermAuto', function(newTerm, oldTerm) {
    /** L@@K HERE **/
    $scope.tableParams.filter({ $: newTerm });
  }, true);
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://rawgit.com/esvit/ng-table/master/dist/ng-table.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
    <div class="col-xs-12">
      
      <!-- GLOBAL FILTER -->
      <form name="searchForm" novalidate>
        
        <h3>Global search with button</h3>
        <div class="input-group">
          
          <input ng-model="globalSearchTerm"
                 type="text" 
                 class="form-control" 
                 placeholder="Search term" 
                 name="searchTerm"
                 required />
                 
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button ng-click="makeGlobalSearch()"
                    class="btn btn-default" 
                    ng-disabled="demo.searchForm.$invalid">
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
            </button>
          </span>
          
        </div>
        
        <h3>Global search without button</h3>
        <div>
          <input ng-model="globalSearchTermAuto"
                 type="text" 
                 class="form-control" 
                 placeholder="Search term" 
                 name="searchTerm"
                 required />
        </div>
      </form>
      
      <!-- NG TABLE -->
      <h3>ngTable directive</h3>
      <table ng-table="tableParams" class="table table-condensed table-bordered table-striped">
        <tr ng-repeat="row in $data">
          <td data-title="'Name'" filter="{name: 'text'}">{{row.name}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Age'" filter="{age: 'number'}">{{row.age}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Money'" filter="{money: 'number'}">{{row.money}}</td>
          <td data-title="'Country'" filter="{country: 'text'}">{{row.country}}</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I will take the "globalSearchTermAuto" as the solution I am looking for. Only question is are there any disadvantage using $scope.$watch ?  Since we won't let use $rootScope inside controllers, is it something like that?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The watcher will be watching only the scope of the controller.

Comment: Hi, if you are OK with the answer, you can mark it as correct. Thanks!